# Как преобразовать число с плавующей точкой double к типу long без потери значений после запятой?

Tags: java

Мне нужно преобразовать число типа double 32,332273 в тип long, но чтобы все числа остались. Я пробывал использовать математическую библиотеку но ничего не вышло, пробовал автоматическое преобразование ситуация аналогична. Подскажите как правильно это можно сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите! число с плавающей точкой – double(float). JAVA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1533284/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-doublefloat-java)

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: В прошлом вопросе у вас упоминались триллионы.  Какой результат вы ожидаете получить из числа `32,332273`?

Answer (score 1):

Никак, тип данных Long не хранит ничего после запятой. При конвертации, значения после запятой будут утрачены. Поэтому если хотите сохранить данные после запятой, воспользуйтесь другим типом данных, который бы это поддерживал

Comment: Аффтар потерял упоминание о триллионах из своего первоначального вопроса, так что там не должно быть "запятой" / центов.

Comment: в любом случае: хоть 33, хоть 33 миллиона - при приведении к типу лонг, все после запятой будет утрачено

Comment: ну при конвертации в единицы миллионы "превратятся" в `32332273`, в случае триллионов - должны добавиться 6 нулей и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно преобразовать следующим образом:

```
double d = 32.332273;
long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(d).replaceAll("\\.", ""));
System.out.println(l); // На выходе: 32332273
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!